# TSQL: Select from set of columns with lowest positive value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Example Schema:

```
RowID    Quantity    ModifiedPrice    GroupPrice    CustomPrice    SalePrice
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        5           20.00            0             15.00          17.00
2        2           14.00            7.00          22.00          0
3        9           10.00            10.00         0              11.00
```

Based on this example table, I would like to be able to select the lowest non-zero value between the four *Price columns in the most efficient/simplest manner possible.

Example Output:

```
RowID    Quantity    EndPrice
------------------------------
1        5           15.00
2        2           7.00
3        9           10.00
```

For extra information, the DB is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  RowId, Quantity,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(price)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  ModifiedPrice AS price
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  GroupPrice
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  CustomPrice
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  SalePrice
                ) qi
        WHERE   price > 0
        )
FROM    mytable
```

This is more readable than a bunch of `CASE` statements.

Note however that this is about `4` times as slow as `CASE` statements.

Here's the test script which parses and yields correct results:

```
CREATE TABLE #t_prices
        (
        RowID INT NOT NULL,
        Quantity INT NOT NULL,
        ModifiedPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
        GroupPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
        CustomPrice FLOAT NOT NULL,
        SalePrice FLOAT NOT NULL
        )

INSERT
INTO    #t_prices
VALUES  (1, 5, 20.00, 0, 15.00, 17.00)
INSERT
INTO    #t_prices
VALUES  (2, 2, 14.00, 7.00, 22.00, 0)
INSERT
INTO    #t_prices
VALUES  (3, 9, 10.00, 10.00, 0, 11.000)


SELECT  RowId, Quantity,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(price)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  ModifiedPrice AS price
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  GroupPrice
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  CustomPrice
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  SalePrice
                ) qi
        WHERE   price > 0
        )
FROM    #t_prices
```

Comment: The LEAST function is one thing TSQL really needs.

Comment: @Welbog: yes. But since we need only positive values here, in this very case it still would have been a bunch of CASE statements.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I would just get fancy with NULLIFs and COALESCEs instead of having to deal with case statements all over the place. But I see your point. In this case there's more code with a LEAST-based solution than a UNION-based one.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: why do you think it's less efficient?

Comment: you know what, i was never aware of this syntax, it gets away with a single table scan ... +1 for that

Comment: My suspicion is right, this is much less efficient than the ugly case statement, test it out on 100,000 rows

Comment: This works excellently and fits in well within the confines of the much larger query which this will be used by. Thanks a lot Q.

Comment: Sam: For the purposes I intend to put it through, the results will be negligible. This query will only be running against a maximum of 50 rows by the time it gets this far.

Comment: Make sure that when you mark this correct you specify its pretty but not super efficient, i suspect a udf is faster and prettier will test it out

Answer (score 3):

I would use a case statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN condition THEN trueresult
  [...n]
[ELSE elseresult]
END
```

Starting with an uncluttered answer, assume none of the values are NULL:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ModifiedPrice > GroupPrice AND ModifiedPrice > CustomPrice AND ModifiedPrice > SalePrice THEN ModifiedPrice
  WHEN GroupPrice > CustomPrice AND GroupPrice > SalePrice THEN GroupPrice
  WHEN CustomPrice > SalePrice THEN CustomPrice
  ELSE SalePrice
END
```

If any values are NULL, then those clauses will return false, so we need to use ISNULL to fix things up and replace NULLS with a large negative number or zero, if you do not expect any negative prices. Assuming no negative prices, I will use zero.

```
CASE 
  WHEN ModifiedPrice > ISNULL(GroupPrice, 0) AND ModifiedPrice > ISNULL(CustomPrice, 0) AND ModifiedPrice > ISNULL(SalePrice,0) THEN ModifiedPrice
  WHEN GroupPrice > ISNULL(CustomPrice, 0) AND GroupPrice > ISNULL(SalePrice, 0) THEN GroupPrice
  WHEN CustomPrice > ISNULL(SalePrice, 0) THEN CustomPrice
  ELSE ISNULL(SalePrice, 0)
END
```

Not pretty, but it will work. If you perform some statistics to see which column is normally the largest value, you can change the query to test that column first. (You cannot merely rearrange my WHEN clauses as written since they each assume the previous price has already been rejected. If CustomPrice was usually the largest, I would swap ModifiedPrice and CustomPrice in the code above.)

Comment: +1. This was almost identical to the way I was already using, but I was hoping to get away from the CASE and compares.

Comment: you need to fix your case statement to match the spec, but this is the fastest approach

Comment: It selects the greatest value, not the least one.

Comment: The highest price? Ouch! No wonder why I am such a poor shopper!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this particular question, but [UNPIVOT](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx) might have been handy here as well. 4 Columns probably isn't too bad, but when you're looking at 30 columns that you want to un crosstab, UNPIVOT is a godsend :-)